# key value pair addition from query result, php

Tags: php, mysqli, associative-array

I am having some issues with the below, wanting to add the query result "id" as the key to the value "concat" -- Do I need a foreach for this? What is the best way?

```
$concatCol = mysqli_query( $connS, "SELECT id, ShipmentNumber, InvoiceNumber, BillofLading from testTable");

$data =array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($concatCol)) {
    $id = $row["id"];
    $ShipmentNumber = $row["ShipmentNumber"];
    $InvoiceNumber = $row["InvoiceNumber"];
    $BillofLading = $row["BillofLading"];

    $concat = $ShipmentNumber.$InvoiceNumber.$BillofLading;

    echo $concat."<br>";

    $data[] = $concat;

}
```

Comment: Your question is not really clear. `$data[]['id'] = $concat;`? Or do you mean `$data[$id] = $concat;`? The first will create a key named `id` for each row, while the second will create a key based on the `$id` for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really sure what your expected output is. But I think one of the following will work for you:

```
$data[]['id'] = $concat;
```

which will result in an array like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
  (
    [id] => ShipmentNumberInvoiceNumberBillofLanding
  )
  [1] => Array
  (
    [id] => ShipmentNumberInvoiceNumberBillofLanding
  )
)
```

The second option would be:

```
$data[$id] = $concat;
```

Which will yield a result like:

```
Array
(
  [1] => ShipmentNumberInvoiceNumberBillofLanding
  [4] => ShipmentNumberInvoiceNumberBillofLanding
)
```

Where the keys `1` and `4` are the `$id` for each returned row. In both example the `ShipmentNumberInvoiceNumberBillofLanding` would of course be the concatenated values for each row.

Comment: thank you, the second one was what i needed, could not for the life of me get it settled

Comment: @user1827601 - No problem, glad I could help, consider an upvote if you think it was helpful =)